# Filter data using datepicker from excel sheet to listbox in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create a excel macro in which,I get the user input from form1 to excel sheet1 and using form2 to get the data from sheet1 by using date-picker and a combo Box to a list box. I followed a tutorial and came up with this , I doesn't show any error output to the Listbox.
P.S I haven't fully completed the instruction from tutorial but the code doesn't run till I have done it. I'm lost in between I can't move onto next steps

```
Private Sub DTPicker2_CloseUp()
Dim i As Long
Me.ListBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To Sheet1.Range("I100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
If Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value And Sheet1.Cells(i, "I").Value >= _
Me.DTPicker1.Value And Sheet1.Cells(i, "I").Value <= Me.DTPicker2.Value Then
Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[The excel file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9b7b8a06241c1f358e0021c33ec2c8ce20200114052820/1a03ef9577d6472d92cefcab592f17b420200114052820/afe7b7)

Comment: Add some `Debug.Print` lines before the `If` statement that shows you all the values you are comparing so you can verify them, and also make sure the dates you are comparing arent actually `String` values, or they will not compare as `Date` values.

Comment: thank you @braX i did what you suggested but the windows just shows random num's here is the screen shot of it. [link](https://imgur.com/L2qEKcV)

Comment: Well those are the values for `i` - you want to see the actual values that are being compared, not the value of `i`

Comment: i used the "Debug.Print Me.ListBox1.Value" i get the return value Null @braX

Comment: well sounds like that gives you something to go on then... that's how to debug it... double check all your values

Comment: you can also break up the if statement into individual pieces to find out which one is not meeting your conditions which narrows is down. you will need to learn how to debug your code at some point, and this should help you.

Comment: Thanks again @braX I will let you know after I solved it .